# drawing images on top of google map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, view, google-maps-markers

i want to do the following. I am having a google map that displays my position. I have created separately a compass. Now what I want is to combine them and put the compass on top of my map. I do not know where to start for it, and how I skould implement it since data of te compass are also being updated every second I move?

If you have any tutorials please give me link cause I have not been able to find any.

In my previous app I have used a class extending Overlay but this was for only putting a pin or something like this.

Comment: Is this for an Android app or a web application?

Comment: android app, I am sorry not to mention it

Answer (score 0):

You may add the image as a custom control: [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom) (it's the home-button in the example)

Comment: how to do it? forgot to mention that is for android app